# How can I fix Warning: C4129 'e': unrecognized character escape sequence

Tags: c

When I write some code with ANSI escape sequence like.... `\e[4m ~ \e[0m`,
I got the error that

> C4129 'e': unrecognized character escape sequence

and the program show me that escape sequence did not set and just indicates `\e[4Hello\e[0`.

How can I fix it?

Comment: yes!! When I change it, it works!!!! yeah~

Comment: @CherryDT You should post that as an answer. I'm surprised there isn't a dup, but I can't find one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `\e` is supposed to insert an ESC character (ASCII code 27), but it doesn't exist in standard C, only in some nonstandard extensions.

You can use `\33` instead<sup>1</sup>. (33 is the octal representation of decimal 27.)

---

<sub>**1:** This will work fine (and is the shortest way) for regular ANSI escape sequences since the following character will always be `[`. But in case you ever need to use the ESC character in other circumstances, please note that you'll need `\033` in case it is followed by a digit between 0 and 7, because otherwise that next digit would errornously be considered part of the octal number. As dxiv mentioned in the comments, it may be the case with some VT100 escape sequences.</sub>

Comment: Guess you meant `\033`.

Comment: Actually `\33` is valid too (an octal escape sequence can have 1-3 digits and ends after the 3rd or once a character is encountered that is not an octal digit). But I changed it now anyway to avoid issues in case the following character would happen to be a valid octal digit too - even though that will never happen for an ANSI escape sequence since the following character will always be `[`.

Comment: True for strict ANSI, but some VT100 escape sequences do start with a digit right after ESC.

Comment: or use `"\x1B"`

Comment: (which has the same length as `\033`)